# Jpa with 2 many to one relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application with hibernate jpa implementation, I have theses 3 tables.

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    private Long eventId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Account{

    @Id
    private Long accountId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Party party;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Event> events;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Party{
    @Id
    private Long partyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "party")
    private List<Account>accounts;
    ...
}
```

I have a accountId, from it, I would like to get all event associated to the party of the account.
Is it possible to do it in one query?

Actually I have done

```
select ce from Event ce where ce.account in 
 ( select ba from Account ba join ba.party p where p.partyId in 
    ( select  py from Party py join py.accounts bao where bao.accountId=:accountId) )
```

any improved query?

Comment: You have accountId and events in one Entity. Why not simply: `Select a.events From Account a Where a.accountId = :accountId` and the dedeuplicate the events in java?

Comment: because that will return only the event of the specified accound it... need to get all account from the party with associated to the account id

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql, if any issue inform me

```
  select * from Event as e 
inner join Account as acc on e.account_accountId = acc.accountId 
inner join Party as p on acc.party_partyId =p.partyId
where acc.accountId=:accountId;
```

Comment: don't work return only event of one account instead of all

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@JoinColumn(name={{joinKeyName}})` to your `@ManyToOne` annotations.

Example:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="accountId")
    private Account account;
```

Then, your HQL query would look like this:

```
select ce from Event ce 
   join fetch ce.account ba 
   join fetch ba.Party py 
   where ba.accountId=:accountId
```